# Cloud Run connect to cloud SQL(postgres) using socket Connection timeout issue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, loopback, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to connect the cloud sql in Cloud run. the same application works well with Google app engine. but the cloud run gives connection timeout error.

```
"unhandled error Error: Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms"
```

My ENV variable

```
PG_DB_HOST='/cloudsql/zoftdesk:europe-west2:zoftdesk'
```

and I'm using same env variable in app engine Flexible Environment and all working good
And my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

and my cloudbuild.yaml file is

```
steps:
# Decrypt the env file
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
   args:
 - kms
 - decrypt
 - --ciphertext-file=.env.enc
 - --plaintext-file=.env
 - --location=global
 - --keyring=birdie
 - --key=birdie-backend
# Build the container image
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
 args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/birdie/birdie-api', '.']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/birdie/birdie-api']
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args:
 - 'run'
 - 'deploy'
 - 'birdie-api'
 - '--image'
 - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/birdie/birdie-api'
 - '--region'
 - 'europe-west2'
 - '--platform'
 - 'managed'
 - '--allow-unauthenticated'
 - '--add-cloudsql-instances'
 - 'zoftdesk:europe-west2:zoftdesk'
images:
 - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/birdie/birdie-api'
```

Comment: Please add more details. It's unclear how you’re connecting (socket or IP connection over VPCs). Which documentation/steps did you follow to connect to the database? By looking your question above, nobody will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: i'm using socket method to connect /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME. and the service account is authorised for cloud sql admin,editor, etc access. and cloud run configuration for enable conection to cloud sql also enabled.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run
this is the steps i followed

Comment: Did you try on app engine standard or flex? Can you share the Dockerfile that you use?

Comment: Hi yes the same project is working fine in app engine.

Comment: Updated the question with dockerfile, clloudbuild.yaml

Comment: actually i tried with Cloud sql proxy in local machine with Socket method. Still same error.

Comment: @Vigikaran, I'm not good in NodeJS. I wondering if you can test locally with the same Node version as AppEngine? I'm not sure that AppEngine is in Node14.

Comment: To look into this further, can you provide more of the error message also where it comes from.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere tried in node 10,12,14. still no luck

Comment: @MrTech ""unhandled error Error: Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms"
" is the error. database connection timeout.  but is working fine if i use the ip instead of socket. but the we can't get the ip from cloud run

Comment: @Vigikaran can you try this value `PG_DB_HOST='/cloudsql/zoftdesk:europe-west2:zoftdesk/.s.PGSQL.5432'`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i'm using loopback postgress connecter with automatically add the '/.s.PGSQL.5432' . but still i tried this and same error

Comment: I don't know what kind of Cloud SQL you are using, MySQL, SQL Server but here is some documentation I found about this. You may use it to verify your set up. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Comment: From my understanding, the connection to Cloud SQL times out because of the cold start for Cloud Run. I found a link here that can help you (https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-minimizing-cold-starts/#:~:text=The%20first%20time%20that%20a,for%20or%20already%20processing%20requests.).

Comment: @MrTech That was my issue. It was set to 1sec. Increasing that timeout to 10s fixed the issue.